# Quicksort doesn't run Java

Tags: java, quicksort

Im trying to make a Quicksort but it always showing up the Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public class Quicksort
{
    void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        _quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }
    private void _quicksort(int[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot = (left + right)/2;
        int l = left;
        int r = right;
        while (l <= r)
        {
            while (arr[l] < pivot)
            {
                l++;
            }
            while (arr[r] > pivot)
            {
                r--;
            }
            if(l <= r)
            {
                int temp = l;
                l = r;
                r = temp;
                l++;
                r++;
            }
        }
        if(left < r)
        {
            _quicksort(arr, left, r);
        }
        if(l < right)
        {
            _quicksort(arr, l, right);
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone know why it doesnt run? It always gives a Error.

The Error message is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Quicksort._quicksort(Quicksort.java:18)
    at Quicksort._quicksort(Quicksort.java:33)
    at Quicksort.sort(Quicksort.java:5)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpGNd.png)

Comment: Might be a good time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Seriously: learning to program is about learning to **debug** problems. Your approach "lets others do the hard work" ... is not efficient. It simply will increase the time you need to become a good programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are a couple of issues with your code. I've listed them below:

1. The variable `pivot` stores the index of the pivot element and not the actual value. So, you can't use `pivot` for comaparison as you have done in the 2 nested while loops. You need `arr[pivot]` instead of `pivot` there.
2. Imagine `arr` looks like `{1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2}`. Here, `pivot` will be equal to `3` i.e. `arr[pivot]` will be equal to `3`. Now, after both the nested while loops terminate, `l` will be equal to `3` and `r` will remain equal to `6`. You then swap `arr[l]` and `arr[r]` and increment both `l` and `r`. Since `l` is still less than equal to `r`, the outer while loop runs for a second time and you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExecption` when the control reaches the second nested while loop. This happens because you're trying to access `arr[7]` (Out of Bounds).

Here's my code:

```
class Quicksort
{
    void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        myQuicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    private void myQuicksort(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
        if (l >= r) {
            return;
        }

        int pivotIndex = (l + r) / 2;
        swap (arr, r, pivotIndex);

        int pivotValue = arr[r];
        int swapIndex = 0;
        int currentIndex = 0;

        while (currentIndex != r) {
            if (arr[currentIndex] < pivotValue) {
                swap(arr, currentIndex, swapIndex);
                swapIndex++;
            }

            currentIndex++;
        }

        swap(arr, r, swapIndex);

        myQuicksort(arr, l, swapIndex - 1);
        myQuicksort(arr, swapIndex + 1, r);
    }

    private void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quicksort quicksort = new Quicksort();

        int[] arr = {3, 7, 1, 0, 4};
        quicksort.sort(arr);

        for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

You should read up on Quicksort. But here are the main points:

1. Choose a random pivot element and swap it with the last element. This makes the implementation much simpler.
2. Loop over the input array and keep a track of a `swapIndex` such that everything before the `swapIndex` is less than the `pivotValue` and everything from the `swapIndex` till the `currentIndex` is greater than (or equal) the `pivotValue`.
3. After the loop runs out, swap the element at `swapIndex` with the `pivot`. This inserts the `pivot` in its correct position.
4. The `pivot` divides the array into 2 subarrays. Call `myQuicksort` on these 2 subarrays.